# IIS can't use port 80 in w2k3

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, exchange, https, port

I have a w2k3 server running IIS and exchange. IIS is used for sharepoint interface. 
Recently, i had to install a self-certificate in the server to use IMAP over SSL with a tool named Selfssl. No problems with this, SSL IMAP works well. But, since that, i have no access to IIS on port 80 and exchange HTTP protocol can't start because it says other process is using the resource. So, port 443 (which was used by ssl exchange) is closed because can't start the service.

Port 80 is used by "system" process ID 4, so i can't start default website in IIS because (the same error) other process is using it.

I read about httpcfg tool so intalled it. When i run it, no addresses seems to be listening.

Anyone knows how can i configure httpcfg.exe so i can re-enable exchange service on port 443 and IIS on port 80?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide information about your IIS bindings?

Comment: I have 5 websites or interfaces running on IIS on different ports. Only default website is on port 80 but can't start.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `netstat -abn |findstr LISTENING`?

Comment: There are a lot of ports listening. 80 is listening (process ID 4). Also 25,42,53,80,88,110,135,143,389,444,445,464,593,etc

Comment: By provide the output, I meant copy-paste the command's output to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to start from the top on this.  When you use the EMC to make changes to certificates, it is sometimes "helpful" about where it puts bindings, including into IIS/website configurations.  If you're running multiple sites, check for two major things in particular:

1. Bindings that are to all addresses instead of the specific one you intended.
2. Bindings that should use hostname differentiators in their configuration but are not doing so even if a given service is not starting.
3. httpcfg wouldn't show you "listening" it only shows you bindings.  So if it shows you anything, then that's what the server is trying to do.

-Mary

Answer (score 0):

I would start by taking a look at what's running on that machine with process explorer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

See if you can find out what child processes are owned by System that might have port 80 open. Most likely you have another service on that machine that seized that port.